# Get `Duration` from `Period` and `LocalDate`

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

Conceptually, given a `Period` (P2Y1M5D) and a `LocalDate` (2016-04-05) to start from, a concrete `Duration` (PT18360H) can be derived.

What's the best (simplest, shortest, most readable) way of doing this in Java?

First thought was `Duration.between(start, start.plus(period))`, but that throws "Unsupported unit: Seconds".

Vanilla Java preferred, but answers using libraries (commons-lang, guava, etc,) are welcome.

Comment: Any downvoters want to suggest some improvements?

Comment: Don't think there's really a way to do this. Years and months don't translate well to days, seconds, etc.

Comment: @Pillar see answer(s) for some ways :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `java.time` only:

```
Duration duration = Duration.between(
    LocalDateTime.of(start, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT),
    LocalDateTime.of(start, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT).plus(period)
);
```

Or even shorter, but with a less well-defined result:

```
Duration duration = Duration.ofDays(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, start.plus(period)))
```